# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install with Flutter and Mac Big Sur with M1

Tags: android, macos, flutter, android-studio

I am getting the following error every time I try to run my app on a real device. Other people can run the same project using the same phone in another computer, so I think the problem is my computer.

Error:
[image: error]

I tried to update the Android Studio and it worked, but then in the next day the same problem started again... So strange!

Here is my Flutter doctor:

Flutter doctor -v:
[image: flutter doctor -v]

I also have this log:

> adb: failed to install
> /Users/matheus/flutter/becare/develop2/becare_app/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
> [2:48:10 PM] [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":28,"type":"event","event":"dart.log","body":{"message":"Error
> launching application on Mi 9 SE.\n","severity":2,"category":8}}
> [2:48:10 PM] [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":29,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"stderr","output":"Error
> launching application on Mi 9 SE.\n"}} [2:48:10 PM] [FlutterRun]
> [Error] [Flutter] Error launching application on Mi 9 SE. [2:48:10 PM]
> [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":30,"type":"event","event":"dart.log","body":{"message":"<==
> [{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"3e89b0c8-b784-4d8e-9f3e-bc3eceed14cb"}}]\r\n","severity":0,"category":8}}
> [2:48:10 PM] [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":31,"type":"event","event":"dart.log","body":{"message":"Process
> terminated! null, SIGTERM","severity":0,"category":8}} [2:48:10 PM]
> [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":32,"type":"event","event":"dart.log","body":{"message":"Process
> exited (sigterm)","severity":0,"category":10}} [2:48:10 PM] [DAP]
> [Info] ==>
> {"seq":33,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"Exited
> (sigterm)\n"}} [2:48:10 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <==
> [{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"3e89b0c8-b784-4d8e-9f3e-bc3eceed14cb"}}]
> [2:48:10 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] Process terminated! null,
> SIGTERM [2:48:10 PM] [DAP] [Info] ==>
> {"seq":34,"type":"event","event":"terminated"

Comment: upgrade your flutter by running `flutter upgrade`. it is problem with the M1 machine. M1 support comes in flutter 2.5.1

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I did it, but the same problem happens :(

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I am always getting "The Flutter Daemon has terminated" on my VS Code too... and showing the log I attached to this question.

Comment: never see such logs. did you tried on different device ? or emulator ?

Comment: Yes. It happens with all Androids, emulator or real device. I even tried to run using Android Studio (because I was using VS code). But the same thing happens. Do you think it might be the adb? I am using the latest version. I tried to download the android-tools from the website and replace the folder but it's the same...

Comment: When I try to run the project and that error shows, usually the device turns offline, checking with the command "adb devices".

Comment: And if I uninstall the old app in the device, it installs the app, but shows that error, like it couldt run the app by itself. I can test the app this way, the problem is that I can't debug it.

Comment: Another awkward thing... It started out of nothing. Then I upgraded Android Studio and it solved the problem. But in the next day the problem came back again 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I installed a software called XDisplay and it looks like its installation was giving some conflict. After uninstalling it, it solved the problem.

Comment: how did you find this? I'm facing a similar issue but I don't find any software installed around the same time that this started happening

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing app from the phone and run again.
If it still doesn't work
And disable debugging in the developer settings and enable it to make sure ADB has access to the device

Comment: I tried this, but I sill have this problem :( the device works with another phone and the same project, but using another computer.

Comment: Then try upgrading to the latest version of flutter, from your flutter doctor it looks like your on 2.2 , latest is 2.5 on stable
`flutter upgrade` then `flutter clean build`

Comment: I did! The same problem is happening :(

Comment: I am always getting "The Flutter Daemon has terminated" on my VS Code too... and showing the log I attached to this question.